# Retrieving data from object

Tags: ios, ios5

I am very new to developing in iOS. I am trying to pass some data through a segue in a table view. Here is what I am calling to pass the data:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowContactDetails"]) {
    ContactDetailsViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Contact *c = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:path.row];
    [dvc setSelectedContact:c];
    }
}
```

It passes fine and when I do a `NSLog` on `selectedContact`, this is what I get:

```
2012-05-21 15:15:42.410 Test[8352:f803] {
category = Prospect;
id = 19895;
label = "John  Doe";
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to access those items individually. I have tried to call things like `objectForKey` but I get an error.

Comment: what is the class? `NSLog("%@", NSStringFromClass(c))`

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output of your NSLog, selectedContact seems to be an NSDictionary object. Try using [selectedContact valueForKey] instead of [selectedContact objectForKey].

For example:

```
NSLog(@"Name: %@", [selectedContact valueForKey:@"label"]);
```

Comment: You can't tell for sure that this is a dictionary just because `NSLog` prints it like this. It can be a custom class with an overridden `description` method for example, which gathers all properties into a dictionary and returning it for logging.

Comment: Yes, it's a dictionary object. It's data that's returned from NSJSONSerialization. I'll try valueForKey at work tomorrow and see if it works.